# Meaning of "would that I might forget him"

Tags: meaning, sentence

> "Would that I might forget him," Ned said bluntly.
>   — *A Song of Ice and Fire*

Does the sentence in quotes mean, "I would forget him if I could"?

Comment: See [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/105969/2085), about using *would* for optative exhortations.

Comment: The usual way this optative is employed, *might* does not quite fit. What does *might* mean here? Is this a non-standard case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to EL&U!

Yes, it's a dated way of saying,

> "I'd forget him if I could."

Perhaps a little less dated, but still quite rare, is the expression "would to God," as in

> "Would to God I could forget him,"

which means, I wish I could forget him [but I can't, even with God's help!].

Or,

> "Would to God I could get him out of my head," Ned said bluntly.