# Using "will" after "if"

Tags: tenses, modal-verbs, conditionals, future, deontic-vs-epistemic

I've been told that native-speakers don't ever use "will" after "if", and that saying it this way is a not-native style.

So from the film (Harry Potter, pt5) I noticed a line that confused me. Look at this:

"Well, if you won't tell her where it is, I will". See that?

What was the necessity of using the future form? What does it add in the meaning? How does it sound to you? Why was namely this sentence used instead of "Well, if you don't tell her where it is, I will"?

Comment: Can you give an example of something specific you were told is "not-native style"? The sentence you give means "If you won't tell her where it is, I will [tell her where it is]," and is absolutely standard in English.

Comment: [*I'll show you mine if you'll show me yours*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I'll+show+you+mine+if+you'll+show+me+yours%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl). I don't understand why anyone would tell OP this "rule". Sales staff are always saying things like [*If you will step this way*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22If+you+will+step+this+way%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl).

Comment: I don't really remember where, but I read that using this belongs to a not-native style. As I said already, I guees native speakers would say "Well, if you don't ...". Can you explain the reason of using it that way?

Comment: Is this question about *if/well* or is it about *won't/don't*?  *Won't* in your sentence is used to indicate *willingness*

Comment: @ Nick: I don't see how we can explain a "reason" for some feature of English that doesn't match reality. Presumably there's a reason why someone *thought* it might be so (or perhaps just why *someone else* misunderstood something), but that's really just speculation. I'll hazard a guess it's something to do with the fact that *If you **won't** do it* implies *If you're **unwilling** to do it, and refuse to change your mind and actually do it*. Whereas *If you **don't** do it* implies nothing at all about your attitude, or why you might not do it.

Comment: My question is about incomprehensibse using the future tense after "will". The rules forbid this.

Comment: @Nick **If you *will* please consult** reputable dictionaries, there you shall find that *will* has many a diverse purpose. OED: “6. In relation to another’s desire or requirement, or to an obligation of some kind. 7. Expressing voluntary action, or conscious intention directed to the doing of what is expressed by the principal verb. 8. Expressing natural disposition to do something, and hence habitual action. 9. Expressing potentiality, capacity, or sufficiency. 10. As a strengthening of sense 7, expressing determination, persistence, and the like.”

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/88251 http://english.stackexchange.com/a/105969 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/77790  and many more.

Comment: Runaway Bunny is a children's book which consists entirely of *if...will* sentences.

Answer (score 29):

The rule you have been told has some validity, but is too general.

English speakers don't use a *will* with simple future meaning after *if*:

> If the plan succeeds, I will come.

not

> *If the plan will succeed, I will come.

But *will* can also convey intention or willingness, so with an animate subject (especially second person) *will* can work

> If you will come, I will talk to you

meaning something like *if you are willing to come*.

So

> If you jump, I'll catch you.

is normal, as is

> If you fall, I'll catch you.

But while

> *If you will fall, I'll catch you.

doesn't make sense,

> If you will jump, I'll catch you.

can make sense, with the special meaning of *if you are willing to jump* - it's an invitation, or a dare.

Comment: And *If you would step this way* is just a softened/politer form if *If you will step this way*.

Comment: I'm going to the prom with Brandon, if his dad will lend him the car. -- from 2 broken girls.

Comment: @Zhang: that is an example of what I said: that means "if his dad is willing to lend him the car", not a simple future.

Answer (score 16):

**SUPPLEMENTARY to Colin Fine's answer:**
Colin Fine explains the most common use of *will* in *if* clauses, which is the use in your example. There are other such situations:

- when *will* is used emphatically in its habitual/insistent sense:

  > If you ***will*** keep bothering me with questions you must expect some answers you don't like.
- when *will* is used in the ordinary futurive sense of a future eventuality accepted as factual. This use is often 'echoic', reflecting a previous speaker's use of *will*:

  > ("John will be here tomorrow") —"Well, if John will be here tomorrow we'd better get that presentation done tonight."
- when *will* is used to indicate an inherent quality or capacity:

  > If your car will hold all of us I don't need to take mine.

Comment: This is the sort of problem that comes from teaching non-native speakers the myth of numbered conditionals, and perhaps the notion that *will* is nothing but a marker of the future in English.

Comment: @tchrist Don't get me started on the *n* conditionals! I cannot decide which approach is more damaging: teaching half-truths and baby rules, as we used to do with NSs and now do with NNSs, or teaching nothing at all, as we now do with NSs.

Comment: And the idea that there is such a thing as a future tense in English.

Answer (score 0):

We do not normally use a pure future will after IF . However, though
rare, it is just possible when we wish to emphasize the idea of 'not
now, but later'.

*If it **suits you**, I'll change the date of our meeting (Type 1)*

*If it **will suit you**, (i.e. not now, but later) I'll change the date of our
meeting*

Comment: I am not sure the *will* in *if it will suit you* is the use of 'future will'. Do you have a source that says it is? Or can you give other examples?