# If I 'will' have the chance to go to the US

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, tenses, future

Is it wrong to say "If I will have the chance to go to the US..."? This is in the context of expressing one's dream/plan in the future. Is it better to say "If I have the chance (in the future, say 10 years from now) to go to the US..."? Not sure if it should have 'WILL' or not. If both are grammatically correct, which is better? Thanks.

Comment: The `will` is not needed, and although i'm not sure it's grammatically incorrect it sounds weird to me.

Comment: will/would is usually used in if/then statements when asking someone to do someone wilfully, as in "If you would please stop smoking, I would appreciate it." In your context, it sounds off, but I'm not sure if it's ungrammatical.

Comment: I hear people ask "Will I have the chance....?" Is this also wrong? In my sentence, is it the word 'If' that makes it wrong? How do we differentiate then, in this context, the chance that we have now, and the chance that we may/will have in the distant future?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Future tense in conditional clauses](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56876/future-tense-in-conditional-clauses)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using “will” after “if”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/181572/using-will-after-if).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Will" is hardly ever used in antecedents of conditionals in English, even when the possibility is conceived as in the far future. It's not clear whether it is ungrammatical, but it is certainly unidiomatic.

The usual way of expressing the distant possibility that you want is "If I ever have the chance ... "

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Based on what you said, is it also wrong to say "If I will have a son..." or "If I will have a successful career (10 yrs from now)..."? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't know about "wrong", but both are unidiomatic.

Comment: Thanks. How should I phrase those two future conditionals (of having a son, or having a successful career in the future) to be idiomatic?

Comment: "If I have", or "If I ever have" to convey the distance in time, or the uncertainty. For the career, perhaps "If I eventually have a successful career".