# A Question on Shakespeare's use of conditionals

Tags: conditionals, shakespeare, conditional-perfect, conditional-future

The following is a big question, but I am really confused by the use of conditional in this Shakespearean excerpt.

From *The Taming of the Shrew*, Act I, Scene I:

> 142   I am agreed; and would I had given him the best
>
> 143 horse in Padua to begin his wooing that would
>
> 144   thoroughly woo her, wed her and bed her and rid the
>
> 145   house of her!

Can someone help me parse out this conditional sentence? It seems that the modern English equivalent would be "I would give the best horse to him who could woo her if I found this chosen man who can do so successfully."

If my reading is correct, here is my doubt: Shakespeare uses 
A) **would I had given** as if he means it as the dependent clause whereas we, in MoE, usually change the word order this way in the dependent clause, as in: "Had I known of the matter, I . . ." Is there something I don't understand?

B) Since the time reference is the future, why **would . . . had** in the first place? Shouldn't it be "I would"?

D) **would . . . *had***? Was this an 16th century equivalent to **would . . . *have***?

Comment: The first _would I had given him_ means "Would **that** I had given him", i.e, I wish that I had given him. Counterfactual, not conditional. Complementizer _that_ was deletable in EMoE, as it is now.

Comment: @John Lawler: hmmm. Does this mean that 'would' meant 'wish'?

Comment: No, it means _would that `S`_ was an idiomatic and poetic way of commenting on outcomes. Burns uses it in the first line of _To a Louse_, in Scots spelling of course: "O wad some Pow'r the giftie gie us. To see oursels as ithers see us!" Happy Burns Night.

Comment: From merriam-webster: c (1) :  strongly desire :  wish <I would I were young again> —often used without a subject and with that in a past or conditional construction <would that I had heeded your advice> (2) —used in auxiliary function with rather or sooner to express preference <he would sooner die than face them>

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/would

Comment: Dictionaries are not the place to look for grammar. _Would_ doesn't normally mean 'I wish"; it does refer to human desire, like _will_, but that's only the deontic sense. Normally the epistemic sense of 'likely, probable' is more prominent. It's in idioms that you get the funny meanings, and only in odd situations.

Comment: @JohnLawler I don’t disagree with you that dictionaries aren’t all that hot on matters of grammar, but if you [pick through the bones in the soup](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/105969/2085), this case seems to be adequately covered there.

Comment: @JohnLawler: I seem to remember, and [Google](http://www.robertburns.org/works/97.shtml) confirms, that the first line of _To a Louse_ is _Ha! whaur ye gaun, ye crowlin ferlie?_. The last stanza does start with your quote of course.